# How can I replace the plug on this cord?

Tags: electrical, wiring, cables

[image: AC power cable]

My cable looks like in the picture. However i want to replace the `B` plug with a specific one for my wall socket. I don't want to mod the original cable. Is the `A` plug standard and can i get a cable with just `A` and exposed wires instead of `B`? Or get `A` on its own.

EDIT: It's European zone, 220-240V cable.

EDIT2: In general, is the modding approach acceptable, if `A` is unobtainable? So i just cut the cable at `B` and put the other plug?

Comment: Have you considered an adapter to convert from B to your wall socket plug? What type of plug does your wall socket use?

Comment: A looks like it be for device, and not standard.  Should be adapters for B to your wall type plug as long as you are not changing voltage or amps

Comment: B looks like an European type plug that has single hot of 230v, neutral, and ground.  Using that type in North America, might not be good, since we use only 120v on a single hot wire.  One reason for different plug types.

Comment: @izzy - can do, but prefer to keep it clean. Wall socket Schuko (2 pin and ground).

Comment: @crip659 - an oven to be exact. EU zone, correct, should have specified. Voltage is the same but current do change, where the wall plug being able to handle much higher current than the one oven will draw. While it's not needed, it's just how the wall socket is.

Comment: Edited question. It's in Europe so to avoid confusion with American standards; and added question about the modding approach.

Comment: Contact the oven makers.  Good chance they sell different B end cables for their ovens.

Comment: Plug B is a "type N" https://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plugs-and-sockets/n/

Comment: @SimonB Close but not exact, it's a Type J used in Switzerland. (Type N is not used in Europe and it has the ground pin closer to the center. It's like a hybrid between type J and the Italian Type I with three pins in line.)

Answer (score 3):

Real simple. Buy a normal extension cord with `B` on both ends (one male one female).   Lop off the male connector and install a male `X` plug, for whatever `X` you are after.  Retrofittable plugs are readily available at home stores.